# Is it possible to implement the Yin-Yang puzzle in C# 5.0 using async?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, scheme, c#-5.0

The puzzle, implemented in Scheme, is as follows:

```
(let* ((yin
     ((lambda (cc) (display #\@) cc) (call-with-current-continuation (lambda (c) c))))
   (yang
     ((lambda (cc) (display #\*) cc) (call-with-current-continuation (lambda (c) c)))))
(yin yang))
```

The goal of the puzzle is to work out and understand the output of this code.

I'm wondering if it's possible to implement code with the same semantics using C# 5.0's new async CPS features.

The part that I'm having trouble grasping, is that the puzzle relies on the semantics of let* as much as call/cc. I'm not sure how to correctly express this interplay in C#.

Comment: I can't read Scheme yet, can you give us another implementation of the puzzle (in pseudo?)

Comment: My answer to this question will probably help considerably. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4070237/how-could-the-new-async-feature-in-c-sharp-5-0-be-implemented-with-call-cc

Answer (score 1):

CPS can get rid of call/cc entirely, so you can definitely implement this in C# by hand-CPS-ing it. Knowing nothing about C#'s automatic CPS-ing, I can't say whether that feature will do this automatically. However, the "async" in the name gives me pause.  The question you give is explicitly related to the *synchronous* evaluation of this expression.

My opinion: I think that translating this to C# is not the fastest way to understand this.

Finally: let* is shorthand for nested bindings. So you can rewrite this as:

```
(let ([yin ...])
  (let ([yang ...])
     ...))
```

... to get rid of the let*. In your case, since 'yang' doesn't depend on 'yin', the effect is that of sequencing.  That is, the continuation captured in the right-hand-side of the 'yin' binding is one that hasn't yet evaluated the 'yang' binding.