# C# await vs continuations: not quite the same?

Tags: c#, continuation

After reading [Eric Lippert’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4071015/33080) I got the impression that `await` and `call/cc` are pretty much two sides of the same coin, with at most syntactic differences. However, upon trying to actually implement `call/cc` in C# 5, I ran into a problem: either I misunderstand call/cc (which is fairly possible), or await is only *reminiscent* of call/cc.

Consider pseudo-code like this:

```
function main:
    foo();
    print "Done"

function foo:
    var result = call/cc(bar);
    print "Result: " + result;

function bar(continuation):
    print "Before"
    continuation("stuff");
    print "After"
```

If my understanding of call/cc is correct, then this should print:

```
Before
Result: stuff
Done
```

Crucially, when the continuation is called, the program state is restored *along with the call history*, so that `foo` returns into `main` and never comes back to `bar`.

However, if implemented using `await` in C#, calling the continuation **does not** restore this call history. `foo` returns into `bar`, and there’s no way (that I can see) that `await` can be used to make the correct call history part of the continuation.

Please explain: did I completely mis-understand the operation of `call/cc`, or is `await` just not quite the same as `call/cc`?

---

Now that I know the answer, I have to say that there’s a good reason to think of them as fairly similar. Consider what the above program looks like in pseudo-C#-5:

```
function main:
    foo();
    print "Done"

async function foo:
    var result = await(bar);
    print "Result: " + result;

async function bar():
    print "Before"
    return "stuff";
    print "After"
```

So while the C# 5 style never gives us a continuation object to pass a value to, overall the similarity is quite striking. Except that this time it’s totally obvious that "After" never gets called, unlike in the true-call/cc example, which is another reason to love C# and praise its design!

Comment: Timwi is correct; await is more like a "local effect" call/cc; this is a subtlety I did not think to call out in my original answer. I've updated it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`await` is indeed not quite the same as `call/cc`.

The kind of totally fundamental `call/cc` that you are thinking of would indeed have to save and restore the entire call stack. But `await` is just a compile-time transformation. It does something similar, but not using the *real* call stack.

Imagine you have an async function containing an await expression:

```
async Task<int> GetInt()
{
    var intermediate = await DoSomething();
    return calculation(intermediate);
}
```

Now imagine that the function you call via `await` *itself* contains an `await` expression:

```
async Task<int> DoSomething()
{
    var important = await DoSomethingImportant();
    return un(important);
}
```

Now think about what happens when `DoSomethingImportant()` finishes and its result is available. Control returns to `DoSomething()`. Then `DoSomething()` finishes and what happens then? Control returns to `GetInt()`. The behaviour is exactly as it *would be* if `GetInt()` were on the call stack. But it isn’t really; you have to use `await` at *every* call that you want simulated this way. Thus, the call stack is lifted into a meta-call-stack that is implemented in the awaiter.

The same, incidentally, is true of `yield return`:

```
IEnumerable<int> GetInts()
{
    foreach (var str in GetStrings())
        yield return computation(str);
}

IEnumerable<string> GetStrings()
{
    foreach (var stuff in GetStuffs())
        yield return computation(stuff);
}
```

Now if I call `GetInts()`, what I get back is an object that encapsulates the current execution state of `GetInts()` (so that calling `MoveNext()` on it resumes operation where it left off). This object itself contains the iterator that is iterating through `GetStrings()` and calls `MoveNext()` on *that*. Thus, the *real* call stack is replaced by a hierarchy of objects which recreate the correct call stack each time via a series of calls to `MoveNext()` on the next inner object.

Comment: Incidentally when you debug an async you see MoveNext as a method name on the breakpoint. That suggest they used the iterator state machine generator from IEnumerable.